# Geographically distributing an Azure based service

Tags: azure, load-balancing, distributed-computing

I have an Azure based web service. The service contains a web based front end that communicates through JSON and Ajax with a WCF service running in the same web role. This in turn communicates with another WCF service that serves as our mid-tier in a separate web role. This communicates with the back-end that consists of two SQL Azure databases and some blob storage. When deployed all of these were placed in the Western Europe region (I'm in the UK). Part of the web service involves uploading multiple potentially large photos. It would make sense if our users in America uploaded to data store and database in America, using a front end and mid-tier hosted in America. Does Azure provide a solution whereby I can replicate my infrastructure across continents and have Azure handle the redirection required? If so, how do I set it up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in Windows Azure using the [Traffic Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx) where you can set it up in 3 different modes:

- Performance (name says it, will try to redirect you to the closest hosted service)
- Failover (redirect in case of an error)
- Round Robin (equally distribute)

Here is an overview of how the performance load balanching method works:

[image]

Note that this only applies to hosted services (not for storage, SQL Azure, ...)

Comment: Brilliant - I can use code in the hosted services themselves to choose storage, SQL Azure etc.

Comment: In this scenario, are we assuming for example that one database exists and storage location, where each application (in a different location) will connect to the same database/storage. Will it help having the applications more local to the user even if the database and storage is not local? What would be the solution to copy/replicate data and file storage? is this something azure does out the box?

Comment: There are a few things available: CDN, read access geo redundant storage, Data Sync, the newly announced SQL Premium Async backups, ... And there's also some guidance from Microsoft here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589779.aspx